# Yii2 - subdomain routing

Tags: yii, routes, yii2

I want to use subdomain as id, and I need dynamic router to do this. In **urlManager**, I added this line:

```
"http://<user:\w+>.local.dev/<controller:\w+>/<action>" => '<controller>/<action>',
```

When I try any action, for example:

```
function actionMyAccount($user){
echo $user;...
}
```

I am not getting anything - the var isn't printed, and script stops working (screen is white). When I remove $user, the page is loading without any problems

How can I achieve subdomain router?

Answer (score 2):

I think your router mapping setting is OK. If you want it to be more precise:

`"http://<user:[^www]\w+>.local.dev/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>" => '<controller>/<action>'`

But to make it work, you'd better double check following two things:

First, your virtual host should have a `*.local.dev`

- `server_name` in `nginx`
- or `ServerAlias` in `Apache`

Then you can use dynamic controller's name as subdomain.

Second, your virtual host should have been configured `rewrite` rules correctly, refer to [Yii2 doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html).

e.g. for `Apache`, just create a `.htaccess` file under `YOUR_APP/web/` folder with following content lines:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```