# Yii2 subdomain URL routing

Tags: apache, yii2

I have two instances. The first one is actually my WordPress page and the second one is for the app. I've created an A record that points to the IP address where the instance for the app is. Let's say it's example.com

When I open app.example.com everything looks fine except links.

This is how I format the link:

```
<a href="<?php echo Url::to(['site/xyz/']);>xyzy/a>
```

However, my links are not formatted very well.

Do you know what can be a problem?

I've found this post: [Yii2 - subdomain routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856741/yii2-subdomain-routing) but I couldn't find it useful.

Maybe I need to add Virtual Host or..?

**UPDATE:**

My UrlManager rules:

```
'rules' => [ 
 'app.example.com/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>', 
 '' => 'site', 
 'logout' => 'site/logout', 
 'sign-up' => 'site/signup', 
]
```

Also, the links are is as the following:

```
<a class=" "href="//import/">anchor</a>
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: can you give an example of this links that are "not formatted very well"

Comment: also, can you show us your current UrlManager Rules ?

Comment: thank you, I added that  to your question.
Where do you expect this //import to go .. you don't have rules for it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some more rules like this:

```
'rules' => [
    'app.example.com/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    'app.example.com/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    'app.example.com/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    //'app.example.com/<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index',
    'app.example.com/<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
],
```

Comment: Almost there. There is a just one small issue. When the app is not on the subdomain, I can create a link with Url::to(['user/']), and it will link to localhost/app/user/ (without "index"), and on production, it doesn't work. I need to create a link with action. For an example, Url::to(['user/index']); Everything else is perfect. Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Actually, links are as the following: //app.example.com/user/index. I'd like to remove these two slashes in the beginning. Also, I'd like to create a link without "index" action. It works on local machine.. Hmm.

Comment: be careful with  the ending slash.
Change the link cal to `Url::to(['user'])`
or update the rule to `..<controller:\w+>/' ...`
. The 2 slashes "//" in the front mean to pick automatically `http` / `https` based on the current link, if you include this in  the rules, it should look better:
'http://app.example.com/<controller:\w+>/'

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, when I add `Url::to(['user'])` the link becomes as a `app.example.com/user/user`. This is really strange. Yes, I know that 2 slashes "//" mean to pick http or https (almost all external JS libraries use this), however, I wonder if there is a way to force it to https, since I'll use SSL. If I write in my rules `https://app.example.com ...` then the link looks as: `https://app.example.com//user/create`.