# How to auto generate sub domain from rules Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Please help!

EX: I have one domain: 
http://www.example.com
and then I want to generate dynamic sub domain
http://user.example.com
Thank!

Comment: Have you done some research on the subject yourself?

Comment: what is `rules Yii2`?

Comment: 'rules' => [
    'http://<name:\w+>.example.local/' => '/shop/index',
    'http://<name:\w+>.example.local/<action>' => 'shop/<action>',
   ] and I user php 7.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 - subdomain routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856741/yii2-subdomain-routing)

Comment: is you need create url from that domain to another domain?

Comment: No I want to generate dynamic subdomain